# PHP files included within functions.php don't work from admin area

Tags: include

I've split my functions.php into multiple files using `require_once`, which works perfectly. However when I add admin functionality (extra panels) in one of the included files, it doesn't work? It's making me put the code in functions.php which I don't want to do.

This is the top of my functions.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', True);

// Includes
require_once('includes/admin.php'); // Admin stuff
```

Comment: You'll have to check if you're in admin: `if ( is_admin() )`. If you're asking the oposite, then your're denying access.

Comment: There is no condition for the included files, I've just tried adding `if(is_admin())` but no luck.

Comment: In short: If you're questioning `if ( is_admin() )` then the following stuff only triggers _if you're on an admin page_. So you maybe have something wrapped into such a statement (or the `! is_admin()` opposite) and therefore your files aren't loading.

Comment: There are no conditions for the included file, I have `require_once('includes/admin.php');` at the top of my functions.php :)

Comment: Turn on all your `DEBUG` stuff including all php error stuff.

Comment: No PHP errors =/

Comment: Update your Q with the debug stuff you added.

Comment: Ok done I've done that

Comment: What about the WordPress debug stuff? Btw: MOVE THAT TO YOUR wp-config.php FILE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you're not including `yourtheme/includes/admin.php`, you're actually including `wp-admin/includes/admin.php`, so pass a full path to the require statement rather than a relative one e.g.:

```
require(get_template_directory().'includes/admin.php');
```

Comment: And why did this work for public files? `/wp-admin`?

Comment: it's to do with the order that PHP looks for files, remember when you're in admin the point of entry is inside the wp-admin folder, whereas for frontend it's one folder up. I imagine if there was an includes/admin.php in the same folder as wp-config.php it would also fail for the same reason without the above fix